# Align 3 divs horizontally and keeping distances between them in a mobile

Tags: html, css, web, alignment, division

I'm trying to align 3 divs but the one in the center(that contains text) is too large and even if i modify the width it doesn't resize. I'm trying to keep also the div on the left with a fixed position so the tag float: left; is not what i think i need.

css:

```
    /*NAVBAR RESPONSIVE*/
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: montserrat;
}

nav {
    background: #0082e6;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

label.logo {
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 80px;
    padding: 0 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 7px 13px;

}
.navmenu:hover {
    background: #1b9bff;
    transition: .2s;

}

tr:hover {
    background: #a5d1de;
    transition: .2s;
}

.checkbtn {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

#check {
    display: none;
}

#screen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10000px;

}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.allineamento {
     float:left;
     margin-left:25px;
}

#nous {
    max-width: 850px;
}

.menu {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#image {
    height: 201px;
}

.menu tr {
  border-bottom: 1pt solid black;
}


/*media query 
  RICORDATI DI METTERE LO SFONDO AZZURRO GIUSTO
  */
@media (max-width: 952px) {
    label.logo {
        font-size: 30px;
        padding-left: 50px;
    }

    nav ul li a {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    #nous{
        width: 670px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 858px) {
    #tablemenu{
        display: none;
    }
    .checkbtn {
        display: block;
    }

    ul {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: #2c3e50;
        top: 80px;
        left: -100%;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all .2s;
    }

    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        margin: 50px 0;
        line-height: 30px;
    }

    nav ul li a {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    a:hover {
        background: none;
        color: #0082e6;
    }

    #check:checked ~ ul {
        left: 0;
    }


}
```

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5edaee6ad5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stile.css">
    <title>SITO ELIAS</title>
    <script>
        /* Storing user's device details in a variable*/
        let details = navigator.userAgent;
  
        /* Creating a regular expression 
        containing some mobile devices keywords 
        to search it in details string*/
        let regexp = /android|iphone|kindle|ipad/i;
  
        /* Using test() method to search regexp in details
        it returns boolean value*/
        let isMobileDevice = regexp.test(details);
  
        if (isMobileDevice) {
            document.write("You are using a Mobile Device");
        } else {
            document.write("You are using Desktop");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
        <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
        <label class="logo">posto del logo</label>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="navmenu">Noi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="navmenu">Missione</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="navmenu">blocco3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="navmenu">blocco4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="navmenu">blocco5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="navmenu">blocco6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="screen">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="tablemenu" class="allineamento">
            <table class="menu" width="30px">
  <tr class="menu">
  <td width="12px" height="59px" >&nbsp;</td>
    <td><a href="#bref">BREF PROFIL</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td width="12px" height="59px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><a href="#comite">COMITÈ DIRECTEUR</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="menu">
  <td width="12px" height="59px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>COMITÈ PROVINCIAUX</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="menu">
  <td width="12px" height="59px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>PARTENARIATS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="menu">
  <td width="12px" height="59px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>RESSOURCES FINANCIÈRES</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="menu">
  <td width="12px" height="59px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>HONNETETÈ ET PERFORMANCES</td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </div>
    <div id="nous" class="allineamento">
        <h1><a id="bref">QUI SOMMES NOUS</a></h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <h1><a id="comite">COMITé DIRECTEUR</a></h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div>
            <div id="img" class="allineamento">
                <img src="bg1.jpeg" id="image"><br>
                <img src="dolphin.png" style="width: 190px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[jsFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/Khagnaccio/k4hygfdr/1/)

I tried using display: inline-box and table but it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome Khagnaccio. I'm afraid your jsfiddle link is not working

Comment: You are using tables and float, very old fashion techniques. I would recommend you using flexbox [https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/], it will solve your issues

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @NicolasTome, but can i give a div an absolute position?

Comment: yes, but you have to make sure you set display to block. Anyway, Have a look at how simple your approach is using flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/nikotome/gd5qwksb/